# Mixin declared without body

Tags: node.js, pug

I am doing the Wes-bos Learn node course.I am on the part of saving stores and using mixins. When I write mixins and run my app it gives this error.

```
Error: C:\Users\ATUL\Downloads\Learn-Node-master\Learn-Node-master\starter-files\views\mixins\_storeForm.pug:1:1
> 1| mixin storeForm(store = {})
   -------^
2| form(action="/add" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" class="card")
3| label(for="name") name
4| input(type="text" name="name")

Mixin storeForm declared without body
at makeError (C:\Users\ATUL\Downloads\Learn-Node-master\Learn-Node-master\starter-files\node_modules\pug-error\index.js:32:13)
at Parser.error (C:\Users\ATUL\Downloads\Learn-Node-master\Learn-Node-master\starter-files\node_modules\pug-parser\index.js:53:15)
at Parser.parseMixin (C:\Users\ATUL\Downloads\Learn-Node-master\Learn-Node-master\starter-files\node_modules\pug-parser\index.js:871:12)
at Parser.parseExpr (C:\Users\ATUL\Downloads\Learn-Node-master\Learn-Node-master\starter-files\node_modules\pug-parser\index.js:204:21)
```

---

This is the file in Mixins (_storeForm.pug)

```
mixin storeForm(store = {})
form(action="/add" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" class="card")
  label(for="name") name
  input(type="text" name="name")
```

---

This is the file in views folder

```
extends layout

include mixins/_storeForm

block content 
  .inner
    h2= title 
    +storeForm({name:'dkjd'})
```

I am new to nodejs/pug/express. What is wrong with this code. This code in the given video works fine but not on my desktop.

Comment: Look the tabs or spaces in `_storeForm.pug`

Comment: OHH thanks this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your mixin `storeForm`, you need to indent `form` and its children once more. Like so:

```
mixin storeForm(store = {})
    form(action="/add" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" class="card")
        label(for="name") name
        input(type="text" name="name")
```