# Do Pug mixins support multiline object destructuring?

Tags: object, pug, multiline, destructuring

My reviewer asked me to use object destructuring in mixins instead of dot object notation.

The problem is simple, if I use object descructuring with the object placed on a single line like this:

```
mixin auth-form({prop1, prop2, prop3, propN})
  ...some pug code
```

It all works pretty well.
But I have mixins that emulate pages and they are using a bunch of different mixins.
So then I try to write it like this:

```
mixin auth-form({
  prop1, prop2, prop3, propN
})

or like this

mixin auth-form({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3,
  propN
})
  ...some pug code
```

I'm getting an error: **Mixin auth-form declared without body**

The only topic I found on the internet is this: [Mixin declared without body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528783/mixin-declared-without-body)

But this topic doesn't help me. =(
Is there a way to fix my problem or does the Pug parser not support multiline mixin parameter destructuring yet?

Comment: GitHub issue (created by OP, nice): https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/3266

Answer (score 0):

This indeed doesn't seem to be possible.

One workaround would be to do the destructuring using [unbuffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code) at the beginning of the mixin's body:

```
mixin auth-form(props)
  - const { prop1, prop2, prop3, propN } = props
  p prop1 equals #{prop1}
  p prop2 equals #{prop2}
  p prop3 equals #{prop3}
  p propN equals #{propN}

//- or

mixin auth-form(props)
  -
    const {
      prop1, prop2, prop3, propN
    } = props
  p prop1 equals #{prop1}
  p prop2 equals #{prop2}
  p prop3 equals #{prop3}
  p propN equals #{propN}

//- or

mixin auth-form(props)
  -
    const {
      prop1,
      prop2,
      prop3,
      propN,
    } = props
  p prop1 equals #{prop1}
  p prop2 equals #{prop2}
  p prop3 equals #{prop3}
  p propN equals #{propN}
```

Note that if the unbuffered code spans multiple lines, the first dash must to be on its own line, and the rest of the unbuffered code must be indented.